# MapReduce counting issue

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm new to hadoop, I try to make a program which will take an input file describing a graph with the edges (ex : `(A,B), (A,C), (B,D), (A,D)` ) I want to count the degrees of each vertex and display it like this :

```
 (A,B) d(A)=3
 (A,C) d(A)=3
 (A,D) d(A)=3
 (A,B) d(B)=2
 (B,D) d(B)=2
 (A,C) d(C)=1
 (A,D) d(D)=2
 (B,D) d(D)=2
```

For the moment I was able to make my map work well (splitting the 2 vertex and emit the `<Key, Value>` as `<Vertex, Edge>` (ex : `<A, (A,B)>` ) but the reduce has an issue that I can't understand. When I do the `context.write(key, result);` outside of the for loop, the result displayed is always 1. I tried to debug but the variable `sum` had the right value.

Reduce :

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
                  Context context
                  ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Text val : values) {
         sum+=1;
         result.set("d("+ key +")=" + sum);
         // WRITE INSIDE THE LOOP
         context.write(key, result);
    } 
}
```

Result :

```
A   d(A)=1
A   d(A)=2
A   d(A)=3
B   d(B)=1
B   d(B)=2
C   d(C)=1
D   d(D)=1
D   d(D)=2
```

Reduce v2 :

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
                  Context context
                  ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Text val : values) {
         sum+=1;
         result.set("d("+ key +")=" + sum);
    } 
    // WRITE HERE NOW
    context.write(key, result);
}
```

Result v2 :

```
A   d(A)=1
B   d(B)=1
C   d(C)=1
D   d(D)=1
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with the code or/and why does it behave this way ?

Comment: where (and how) do you declare `result`?

Comment: Your code is correct. Make sure that you run the latest version of the runnable jar. It may be the case that you are running a previous version of your code. Compile and make the jar again to be sure.

Comment: @vefthym public static class IntSumReducer 
  extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
 private Text result = new Text();

this is just a Text attribute for the Reducer
and I'm using eclipse so it generates a new jar everytime I execute my code. + I tried in console version (I thought that there was a bug in eclipse) and used the right commands to create the jar and used it but same result...

Answer (score -1):

There's a problem with both the code versions of Reducer. You can go with v2 but with a change Pull this `result.set("d("+ key +")=" + sum);` out of the loop.

Use this code:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
                  Context context
                  ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Text val : values) {
         sum+=1;
    } 
    result.set("d("+ key +")=" + sum);
    // WRITE HERE NOW
    context.write(key, result);
}
```

Comment: result is written to context and is obviously a Text, not a Set

Comment: I already tried that and same issue... why does the variable sum resets to 1 ?